# SQL give cells the same value if cell in another column is partly similar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm pretty new to SQL. And I'm trying the following.
I have the following table1 with Columns group and description.

Table1 Example

[image: Table1 Example]

I want to check if the cell values are partly the same. Like in this case Group101 and Group101D1. Now I want to take the description from the value with D1 and put it in the description column of the one without D1.
And do this for all the cells where the Group value is partly the same.

```
SELECT [Group]
  ,[Description]
FROM [Table1]
update [Table1]
set Description = (Select [Description] from [Table1] where [Group] like '%Group101D1%')
where Address like '%Group1%'
```

This is how far I came. I can make it work for one but have to split it up and make it work for all of them.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: My database name is GroupInformation and im using Microsoft sQL server management studio 2017.

Comment: How many digits are the group number and is the width always fixed?

Comment: Is the naming always the same? I.e. will the difference always be the last two characters? And are you sure you will not get any duplicates this was? (I.e. you have both Group101D1 and Group101D2). IF this is the case, you can create a self-join of the table on `a.description = LEFT(b.description, LEN(b.Description -2))`. I can write it out for you if you can confirm this would work.

Comment: Add your expected output

Comment: The Group number can be 3 or 4 numbers. The rest is always the same.

Comment: My suspected output is that group101 will have the description from Group101D1. And Group105 will have the description from Group105D1. etc.. But the group can also have 4 numbers like Group1015 and that one will need the description of Group1015D1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.Description AS desc_dest, t2.Description AS desc_src
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t2.[Group] LIKE t1.[Group] + '[A-Z]%' AND LEN(t1.[Group]) <= 9
)

UPDATE cte
SET desc_dest = desc_src;
```

### Demo

Comment: great solution! maybe there could be a little problem with update order in case of many secondary groups (D1, D2.. Dn)

Comment: @MtwStark I slightly modified the join condition to handle secondary groups.  Now any secondary group would only match to a single primary.  But it doesn't make sense anyway to have more than one secondary because the secondary is supposed to update the primary.

Comment: Tim I was thinking about the possibility to have to handle many updates queued (group101D1, group101D2.. ) they all match primary group (group101) but it is not known which description will be used in the update.. depending on table indexes (or optimizer) I guess the D2 version will win the run.. but it is not sure, isn't it?

Comment: Before this you need to give us logic regarding which one will be used in the update.  Afterwards, then worry about the query.

Comment: This worked perfectly after some adjustments thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to get consistency between all descriptions that only differ in the last two characters, the following should to the trick:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        a.Description
        , b.Description AS Descriptionb
    FROM 
        TABLE1 a  
        JOIN [Table1] b ON LEFT(a.[Group], LEN(a.[Group]) - 2) = b.[Group]
) 
update CTE 
set Description = Descriptionb
```

The self-join establishes that we look for all descriptions where the last 2 characters from set a (`Group101D1`) are removed so we end up with `Group101`. We then look for a match in set b. If we find it, we set the values of b to match the values in a.

This means the description of `Group101D1` will be set to  `Group101`, as would Group101XX. It also should allow for handling of `Group1010404D1` to change `Group1010404`.

Edit: Switched the UPDATE around. I read things wrong and it would have updated the wrong values.

Edit2: As Tim said, my join was wrong. The above should work, though.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is the following:

```
SELECT [Table1].[Description] 
, [Table2].[Description] 
,[Table1].[Group] 
,[Table2].[Group]
--update [Table1] set [Table1].[Description] = [Table2].[Description]
FROM [BVCIOList_DOW].[dbo].[Table] Table1
INNER JOIN [BVCIOList_DOW].[dbo].[Table] Table2
ON [Table2].[Group] = [Table1].[Group] + 'D1'
```